# Assign each value of an array to a Queue Collection

Tags: c#, .net

I have an Queue Collection of

```
var queue = new Queue<ExchangeEmailInformation>(mailInformation);
```

which contain two records. I have also Guid array

```
public static List<Guid> FolderId { get; set; }
```

which contain two guid records. I need to reassign these guids to Queue collection of property
FolderId.How can I possible this?
Below are the ExchangeEmailInformation class

```
 public class ExchangeEmailInformation:IEmailInformation
    {
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Sender { get; set; }
        public AttachmentCollection Attachment { get; set; }
        public Guid FolderId { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Where is `List<Guid> FolderId` assigned? Is it the same class that `var queue` is defined and filled? Do you need to make sure that the items remain in the queue? Does it matter which guid gets assigned to which ExchangeEmailInformation?

Comment: for example FolderId[0] to be reassigned to first Record of the Queue Collection of property FolderId and FolderId[1] to be reassigned to the second record and so on

Comment: List<Guid> assigned before Queue Collection to be filled. The Queue collection has two records. the problem while assigning the Guid to the queue is both the records in the queue contain the same FolderId.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentQueue = queue.ToList();
                            for (int i = 0; i < currentQueue.Count; i++)
                            {
                                currentQueue[i].FolderId = FolderId[i];
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than coping the values to a list you can just enumerate over the queue and keep a counter

```
int i =0;
foreach (var email in queue)
{
    email.FolderId = this.FolderID[i];
    i++;
}
```